# Undefined index. database column name undefined

Tags: php, database, indexing, undefined

I've tried a lot of ways to execute this and it still says my column is `undefined`. I thought I didn't link it to my database correctly or something but even after searching for solutions here I still get the same error. I'm super newbie in coding especially in PHP and this problem had literally gone for days.

[image: Errors]

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Post your code and form that submits the data otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `undefined` for column because you have not check each of those with isset() or empty()

you should do like

```
$menuname = ( !empty($_POST['menu_Name']) )?mysqli_real_escape_string($query, $_POST['menu_Name']):'';
```

or

```
$menuname = ( isset($_POST['menu_Name']) )?mysqli_real_escape_string($query, $_POST['menu_Name']):'';
```

also looks your query is wrong.

it should be like

```
INSERT into mytable (mycolums) VALUES ('myvalues')
```

where 
mytable is the name of table
mycolums can be name of one or more columns with comma saperated
and
myvalues can be value of each colums like 'col1val','col2val, ...

don't forgot to vote up if it helped you